# Show the 'Use camera' option in the WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I'm implementing a WKWebView that loads a payment page with credit card information; I need to show the 'Use camera' option along with the keyboard just like safari browser.

I have added the camera permission for the info.plist, but nothing is working on the webview!! Should I select a specific keyboard?

I am using iOS 11 with swift 3.2 or 4.0

Here it is my code

```
    var webView : WKWebView = WKWebView()
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()   
    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)      
    webView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height)       
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.scrollView.delegate = self
    webView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    webView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
    self.view.addSubview(webView)

    let newurl = URL(string:"https://xxxxxxxxx")
    let newrequest = URLRequest(url: newurl!)                    
    self.webView.load(newrequest)
```

plus Camera permission

```
Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   
Value     :  $(PRODUCT_NAME) Use camera
```

Comment: Can you show some code which you did?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code

Comment: you need to WkScriptMessage, to fire the camera button event.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm researching and it seems that WKWebView doesn't support camera access. Just Safari does. Is that right?

Comment: Kindly find my answer with a new post

Answer (score 0):

After long research I found [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) with its delegate class [SFSafariViewControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontrollerdelegate) could be used to show the scan card option available on safari, but with limited capabilities compared to the WKWebView, so it's up to your business case to use it or not, but anyway this is the only option available right now according to my knowledge.

Please note that, in order to make it work, you should enable the scan card option on your mobile by changing the settings under the privacy.

Also, you need to be sure that the payment page includes the iOS meta tags to let safari detect the credit card fields.